# BindingAdapter with 3 parameters throws compile error when together but works separately

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have created `BindingAdapter` to make clickable part inside `TextView`. I have used 3 parameters, one string resource with placeholder for clickable part (`textWithPlaceholder`), second part with clickable part (`textClickablePhrase`) and last one for listener (`onPhraseClick`). When building the app, it fails with upcoming error.

```
Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:onPhraseClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.TextView.
```

The strange thing is when I try the same code without first two parameters (the strings), it can build. Even if I try to build app without last parameter (listener), it can build. So the code works but it doesn't work together.

```
<TextView
  <!-- another attributes -->
  app:textWithPlaceholder="@{@string/text_with_placeholder}"            
  app:textClickablePhrase="@{@string/clickable_phrase}"
  app:onPhraseClick="@{() -> viewModel.onPhraseClicked()}" />
```

```
@BindingAdapter("textWithPlaceholder", "textClickablePhrase", "onPhraseClick")
@JvmStatic
fun TextView.setClickablePhrase(
   textWithPlaceholder: String,
   textClickablePhrase: String,
   onPhraseClick: View.OnClickListener) {
      // setting Spannable and click listener
}
```

I expect the 3 parameters should work together but they works only separated.

EDIT: 
It can build even like this but I think it is not right solution because it is not defined right. **All parameters are mandatory** and it should be able to be defined in this way and not to use workaround to make it optional.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["textWithPlaceholder", "textClickablePhrase", "onPhraseClick"], requireAll = false)
```

Comment: what are doing with onPhraseClick in BindingAdapter. the error says there is no setter for attribute onPhraseClick

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for reply. I don't think it is important for error because databinding cannot match this `BindingAdapter` function with attributes in XML layout. So body of this function is not important here, it can be empty and it should work.

Comment: It is important cause you have this onPhraseClick: View.OnClickListener. you have OnClickListener on the same and when you click a phrase you want the method in view model to be invoked

Comment: I am 100% sure that it doesn't depend on method body. As I said it can be empty. For example: `app:onPhraseClick="@{() -> viewModel.onSkipClicked()}"` used only separately with `@BindingAdapter("onPhraseClick")` and empty body works.  So there is no need to use the listener in method body even if it is mandatory parameter.

Comment: If it works separately it should work with multiple attributes i cannot think of anything else right now. may be i am missing something. will let you know if i figure this out.